# you can use Control+⬅️ to option desktop on mac . but is there a way to creat a new desktop by applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript

you can use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>⬅️</kbd> to option desktop on Mac . but is there any way to **creat a new desktop** by **applescript**?

Comment: I can't quite understand what you're asking. Can you try again?

Comment: The questions aims at "Spaces" and how to create new spaces automatically. AFAIK no chance... There are a few unanswered questions about spaces here!

Answer (score 0):

By the help of [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/152797), this works for me:

```
do shell script "/Applications/Mission\\ Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission\\ Control"

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dock" to click button 1 of group 1

do shell script "/Applications/Mission\\ Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission\\ Control 1"
```

If you want to activate the new desktop:

```
do shell script "/Applications/Mission\\ Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission\\ Control"

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dock"
    click button 1 of group 1
    click last button of list 1 of group 1
end tell
```